# Binarized Image Filtering Methods Suggestion

Tags: image-processing, filtering

i have binarized an image :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_g1PNBVdIpGM1EyU0lNdHd1ZU0

I want to remove isolated pixels or do filtering. What methods should i use ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Dilation and Erosion
You could find source here
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html

Comment: how about i use gaussian filter ? @Yirui

Comment: It will serve as a smooth filter, i.e. it will broaden your characters. But yes, this filter will also somehow filter out the isolated pixels.